# If you run python random function in a loop a hundred/thousands can numbers repeat themselves? I'm aware of how seeding works

Tags: python

```
for I in range(100):
    print(random()) # everything being imported and using the system time as seed.
                    # is it possible to get repeating random values?
```

Comment: Yes, that's what random means. That being said, I'm sure you can look up the repeatability characteristics somewhere.

Comment: You can get a repetition even with *two* calls.

Comment: Gosh Random.... Yep, makes sence.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> Almost all module functions depend on the basic function [random()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random), which generates a random float uniformly in the semi-open range [0.0, 1.0). Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces 53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1. The underlying implementation in C is both fast and threadsafe. The Mersenne Twister is one of the most extensively tested random number generators in existence. However, being completely deterministic, it is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic purposes.

It means there is a possibility to getting same values in each iteration. But it is so small possibility.

Comment: How small is the possibility? (I'm wondering because you quote that entire stuff about Mersenne Twister.)

Comment: Well, I'm not able to calculate it, but if you really wondering that, i suggest you to check this https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307599438_Convergence_analysis_of_random_generators_in_Monte_Carlo_simulation_Mersenne_Twister_and_Sobol
and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator .
Mersenne Twister is a deterministic algorithm, produces 32-bit or 64-bit numbers (thus usable as source of random bits). Means that size of produced numbers limited. Also check this https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/53475 overview on Mersenne Twister to get summary information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require any specific value range, you can add `i` variable to each iteration to ensure that the values ​​are not repeated. but it doesn't make much sense if you use `random()`.

Otherwise each iteration can be repeated without problems, that is the meaning of random.

```
import random

for i in range(100):
    print(random.random() + i)
```

Comment: How would adding `i` to random() ensure that the values are not repeated? Isn't `random() + i` just as likely as `random()` in a uniform distribution?

Comment: No, because `random()` only return values betwhen `0` and `1`